# Why would I get broken lines in a SSRS 2005 line graph

Tags: sql-server-2005, reportingservices-2005, business-intelligence

My dataset consists of only values > 0 or NULL so I don't understand why my line graph broke at the end of the line and didn't go all the way to the end of the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide much information but one thing that can happen with charts in Microsoft software is that the X range is usually pulled from the first series. So other series can then be only over part of the chart.